# Is there a way to convert a base type stored in QVariant without specializing the cast?

Tags: c++, qt, c++14, qvariant

Let's consider this example:

```
QVariant v1(1);
QVariant v2("goofy");
QVariantList list;

list << v1 << v2;

for (const auto& var : list) {
   qdebug() << var;

   // nasty part
   if (var.type == QVariant::Int) {
      int value = var.toInt();

      // do something
   } else if (var.type == QVariant::QString) {
      QString value = var.toString();

      // do something
   }
}
```

The debug function shows the internal storage type of *QVariant*:

```
QVariant(int, 1) QVariant(QString, "goofy")
```

Is there a way to avoid the `if`s and do an explicit cast in order to access the internal type? More specifically, to get the value I would like to be able to write something like this:

```
auto value = var.ToData();
```

**Edit**: Since QVariant can hold a lot of type and you can even add custom types on it, it would be enough restricting the problem only to base types ***(int, double, bool, string)***

Comment: That's the price you pay for using a variant type. `qdebug()` works with `QVariant` because Qt implements `QDataStream& operator<< (QDataStream& s, const QVariant& p)`

Comment: That `operator<<``also does much the same "nasty ifs"

Comment: Interesting question, and I think it's not possible because the `auto` is resolved at compile time while the `QVariant` type is set at runtime. If your variant variable was defined at compile time with templates (so not like QVariant does it), it would be doable for sure.

Comment: This is how the data is stored in `QVariant` : https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qvariant.h.html#QVariant::Private

Comment: What would `decltype(var.ToData())` be?

Comment: @Caleth it does not exists `toData()`, but as Jaa-c suggested, variant is resolved at Runtime meanwhile decltype is resolved at compile time

Comment: @Moia my question was leading you to the conclusion that `toData` *can't* exist, because it doesn't have a unique type.

Comment: Please provide some representative examples of exactly what operations you wish to perform on the values - try to be comprehensive, but don't add things you "potentially" might wish to do, but don't have immediate need for. Overgeneralizing may make a solution impossible.

Comment: `switch(var.type)` and a couple case statements would grab the basic types you are interested in, leaving the default for anything else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not possible. As any other variant, `QVariant` basically acts as a union. Unless you know the type of the data, you can't get it. If your imaginary code `auto value = var.ToData();` should work, the type of `value` would have to be resolvable at compile time - but then it wouldn't be a variant at all.

The whole point of variant is that it enables you to store multiple types in a single value, all done in runtime. Internally, it stores the type of it's value, but it's a runtime value - so if you don't know the type exactly, there is no other way than to make a long switch.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but at a price - and `QVariant` doesn't do it. There are two related approaches:

1. `QVariant` could dispatch all operators to the type-specific ones at runtime, e.g. adding two `QVariant`s that hold integers could invoke `int operator+(int,int)`. It's not done because it is hard to do it in a sufficiently general way, but if you had a few types in mind - you certainly could make your own type that does it. It could, internally, use `QVariant`, but I'd be leery of exposing it indiscriminately as a `QVariant`. It could be convertible to a `QVariant`, though, so that you could pass the type where a variant is expected, but not have it itself be a variant - i.e. use composition, not inheritance.
2. `QVariant` could implement templated type forwarding that would deduce the type based on what operations you perform on it, using SFINAE and template expressions, and replace the operations on `QVariant` with operations on the contained type, with no runtime overhead. Writing out a sufficiently specific expression would deduce the type, and if it wasn't specific enough, then you'd have to provide type hints - just like in any functional language with type deduction.

When you have a small list of types in mind, either approach could work very well, but with the plethora of types `QVariant` has to support - including a-priori unknown user types - the general approach to have so many limitations as to be unusable. It's hard to tell without knowing what you do with those values. More could be said about it when given less laconic of a description than `//do something`.

Comment: Could you please provide an example for the option 2?

Comment: restricting the problem only to int, double, bool, string would be enough, ignoring all the Qt and custom types